Neovim: <leader>pv key mapping not working for :Ex command in init.lua
just following theprimeagen neovim setup tutorial, try to map Ex to pv not working.
print("Setting leader key")
vim.g.mapleader = " "
print("Setting key mapping")
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>pv', vim.cmd.Ex)
print("Configuration loaded")


Setting leader key
Setting key mapping
Configuration loaded
Press ENTER or type command to continue

the debug info seems to be working
and also in :map
n  <Space>pv   * <Lua 29: vim/_editor.lua:0>  

but when i try : pv
E492:Not an editor command: pv



You set a Normal mode mapping, as in :help key-mapping. This is accessible directly from Normal mode by pressing the sequence of keys  pv (that's SpacePV).
You must not prefix a colon.
You're confusing mappings with user-defined commands, explained in :help user-commands.
By the way, user-defined commands have to start with a capital letter to avoid confusion with the build-in Ex commands. Even if you were defining a command, it would need to be either :Pv or :PV.
My recommendation would be to familiarize yourself with your editor's features by means of the built-in documentation like :help user-manual before trying to follow online resources. You need to understand the basics before you can tweak them. Just my two cents, though.

thank u lol, what a stupid midunderstanding.
